# Synchronise SharePoint folder - not full document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Is it possible to synchronise specific folder(s) instead of the whole SharePoint library?

I am able to sync the full document library, but the library will become huge with time and I don't want my hard drive filled with stuff I don't need.

I can choose the folders I want to sync if I am using my personal/company OneDrive for Business but it's not the same with SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the OneDrive for Business client. The OneDrive client is currently in preview for sync'ing SharePoint Doc Libs (SharePoint Online only) and is expected to go GA at the end of the year. This updated OneDrive client allows for selective sync.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Trevor. I couldn't find anything from Microsoft saying that it isn't possible (or when/if it will be), so I am just curious if you have seen this information somewhere?

Comment: It's outlined here, an announcement about the Next Gen Sync Client from many months ago - https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/30/meet-the-new-onedrive-for-business/